# Custom filter based on data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, filters, lookup-filter

we have a data extension with some user status asigned to identificators.

Is it possible to make a filter shows only the possible values of that field based on a DE with those ids and its meaning instead the standard "is equal", "contains", etc?

**UPDATE**:

I have a Data Extension with this data

[image]

and another DE with orders info

[image]

I would like to filter that DE to get only the scheduled orders (order_status=2) but in a easy way. I don't want marketing staff dealing with ids when composing filters. I'd like something like this when composing filters:

[image]

I've tried with data relationships but it doesn't work

thank you in advance

Luis

Comment: Can the question be re-phrased or added with screenshot or the example input and a desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to manually filter and display values in UI, you can create a [Filtered Data Extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_filtered_de.htm&type=5):

1. Hover over Subscribers.
2. Click Data Extensions.
3. Click Create.
4. Select Filtered Data Extension.
5. Click OK.
6. Select a standard data extension to filter as the source data extension.
7. Click OK.
8. Drag Fields, Filters, or Measure from the left column to the Create Filter canvas.
9. Select an AND or OR operator. You can group your criteria by hover over the grouping operator so that it turns a darker blue, and click to change the operator. If you choose AND, the record must meet all criteria to be included in the group. If you choose OR, the record must meet one of the criteria, not necessarily all criteria, to be included in the group.
10. Click Save & Build.
11. Enter a Name for the filtered data extension.
12. Enter a Description for the filtered data extension.
13. Select a folder in which to store the filtered data extension. Or select New Folder to create a folder to store the filtered data extension.
14. Click Save.

This can also be automated: [Automatically refresh a Filtered Data Extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320525&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Thats the way to create filtered DE, but what I want SFMC to do is showing DE text values as options, but using Ids to build the filter. (I updated the question with a visual example)